# Как заархивировать директорию

Tags: c#

Есть директория, из содержимого которой нужно создать архив. При этом архив должен создаваться в потоке, а не сохраняться в виде файла на диске.

Существует метод `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(string sourceDirectoryName, string destinationArchiveFileName)`, но он сохраняет результат в файл. Есть ли что-нибудь похожее, но сохраняющее результат в поток?

Желательно, чтобы это были классы из пространства имен `System.IO.Compression`, т.е. обойтись без сторонних библиотек.

Comment: OutOfMemory, когда папка в память не влазит, вас устроит? Архивация папки всё таки неочевидный процесс, в отличие от файла.

Comment: @Monk, вполне устроит.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/319438/How-to-Compress-Decompress-directories - только в упаковке папки вместо файлстрима используйте нужный вам, ну и не закрывайте его.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В nuget есть библиотека [DotNetZip](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip/), она позволяет архивировать в поток без предварительного сохранения на диск. Правда, это чревато OutOfMemoryException. Во всяком случае, у меня при попытке архивирования в поток это исключение выпадало регулярно, вследствие чего пришлось вернуться к идее сохранения на диск.

Comment: Видимо, придется предварительно сохранять данные в файл на диске. А сторонней библиотеки хотелось бы избежать (не так давно от нее избавились).

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.IO.Compression;
private void Compress()
        {
       ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(DirectorySrc , DirectoryDist);
}
```